# How do I state a lemma that does not respect sort constraints (for using OFCLASS)

Tags: isabelle

How can I state a lemma in Isabelle/HOL that does not obey sort constraints?

To explain why that makes sense, consider the following example theory:

```
theory Test
imports Main
begin

class embeddable = 
  fixes embedding::"'a ⇒ nat"
  assumes "inj embedding"

lemma OFCLASS_I:
  assumes "inj (embedding::'a⇒_)"
  shows "OFCLASS('a::type,embeddable_class)"
apply intro_classes by (fact assms)

instantiation nat :: embeddable begin
definition "embedding = id"
instance
  apply (rule OFCLASS_I) unfolding embedding_nat_def by simp
end

end
```

This theory defines a type class "embeddable" with one type parameters "embedding". (Basically, the class embeddable characterizes countable numbers with an explicit enumeration, but I chose this simply to have a very simple example.)

To simplify instance-proofs for the type class, the theory states an auxiliary lemma `OFCLASS_I` that shows goals of the form `OFCLASS(...,embeddable)`. This lemma can then be used to solve the proof obligations produced by `instance`.

First, why would I even want that? (In the present theory, `apply (rule OFCLASS_I)` does the same as the builtin `apply intro_classes` and hence is useless.) In more complex cases, there are two reasons for such a lemma:

- The lemma can give alternative criteria for instantiation of a type class, making subsequent proofs simpler.
- The lemma could be used in automated (ML-level) instantiations. Here using `intro_classes` is problematic, because the number of subgoals of `intro_classes` can vary depending on what instance proofs have been performed earlier. (A lemma such as `OFCLASS_I` has a stable, well-controlled subgoals.)

However, the above theory does not work in Isabelle/HOL (neither 2015 or 2016-RC1) because the lemma does not type-check. The sort constraint "embedding::(_::embeddable => _)" is not satisfied. However, this type contraint is not a logic necessity (it is not enforced by the logical kernel but instead of a higher level).

So, is there a clean way of stating the theory above? (I give a somewhat ugly solution in my answer, but I am looking for something cleaner.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is a different solution that does not require to "clean up" after proving the lemma ([this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34974802/2646248) requires to "repair" the sort constraints afterwards).

The idea is to define a new constant (`embedding_UNCONSTRAINED` in my example) that is a copy of the original sort-constrained constant (`embedding`), except without sort constraints (using the `local_setup` command below). Then the lemma is stated using `embedding_UNCONSTRAINED` instead of `embedding`. But by adding the attribute `[unfolded embedding_UNCONSTRAINED_def]` the lemma that is actually stored uses the constant `embedding` without sort constraint.

The drawback of this approach is that during the proof of the lemma, we can never explicitly write any terms containing `embedding` (since that will add the unwanted sort constraints). But if we need to state a subgoal containing `embedding`, we can always state it using `embedding_UNCONSTRAINED` and then use, e.g., `unfolding embedding_UNCONSTRAINED` to transform it into `embedding`.

```
theory Test
imports Main
begin

class embeddable = 
  fixes embedding::"'a ⇒ nat"
  assumes "inj embedding"

(* This does roughly:
   definition "embedding_UNCONSTRAINED == (embedding::('a::type)=>nat)" *)
local_setup {* 
  Local_Theory.define ((@{binding embedding_UNCONSTRAINED},NoSyn),((@{binding embedding_UNCONSTRAINED_def},[]),
      Const(@{const_name embedding},@{typ "'a ⇒ nat"}))) #> snd
*}

lemma OFCLASS_I [unfolded embedding_UNCONSTRAINED_def]:
  assumes "inj (embedding_UNCONSTRAINED::'a⇒_)"
  shows "OFCLASS('a::type,embeddable_class)"
apply intro_classes by (fact assms[unfolded embedding_UNCONSTRAINED_def])

thm OFCLASS_I (* The theorem now uses "embedding", but without sort "embeddable" *)

instantiation nat :: embeddable begin
definition "embedding = id"
instance
  apply (rule OFCLASS_I) unfolding embedding_nat_def by simp
end

end
```

Answer (score 1):

The checking of the sort constraints can be disabled temporarily on the ML-level, and reactivated afterwards. (See the complete example below.) But that solution looks very much like a hack. We have to change the sort constraints in the context, and remember to restore them afterwards.

```
theory Test
imports Main
begin

class embeddable = 
  fixes embedding::"'a ⇒ nat"
  assumes "inj embedding"

ML {*  
  val consts_to_unconstrain = [@{const_name embedding}]
  val consts_orig_constraints = map (Sign.the_const_constraint
                                @{theory}) consts_to_unconstrain
*}
setup {*
  fold (fn c => fn thy => Sign.add_const_constraint (c,NONE) thy) consts_to_unconstrain
*}

lemma OFCLASS_I:
  assumes "inj (embedding::'a⇒_)"
  shows "OFCLASS('a::type,embeddable_class)"
apply intro_classes by (fact assms)

(* Recover stored type constraints *)
setup {*
  fold2 (fn c => fn T => fn thy => Sign.add_const_constraint
            (c,SOME (Logic.unvarifyT_global T)) thy)
              consts_to_unconstrain consts_orig_constraints
*}

instantiation nat :: embeddable begin
definition "embedding = id"
instance
  apply (rule OFCLASS_I) unfolding embedding_nat_def by simp
end

end
```

This theory is accepted by Isabelle/HOL. The approach works in more complex settings (I have used it several times), but I would prefer a more elegant one.